# C++ Class Constructor defined public, says it's protected

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, public, protected

I have a project going with multiple levels of inheritance. It goes like this

`XMLs -> Entity -> Item` and then there are numerous item classes that inherit from Item which then inherit from Entity. Now, I have each class defined as shown

```
    class Entity: public XMLs
    {
     public: 
            Entity() {}
            virtual ~Entity() {};
         //other functions
    };
```

This is the one that is giving me trouble. Whenever I try to create an Item object or any type of object at all really in my main function, it gives me the following error

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream: In constructor ‘Entity::Entity()’:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:363:7: error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]’ is protected

What does this mean? Everything I google about constructors and protected involves the keyword protected where I have public.

Comment: You're not posting your actual code. Put some effort into *narrowing the problem down* and then post a *representative, minimal* example.

Comment: The answer is in an error message you're not sharing.  The error message that mentions a specific line in your own source file.

Comment: @DrewDormann agree - so close as too localized

Comment: Someone's answer fixed it for me but it said their post was deleted. I just needed to use std::ostream* instead of std::ostream.

Comment: @user1357707: That was Robᵩ's answer, but I believe he deleted it because my answer is more thorough but came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the message again  It doesn't say your constructor is protected, it says `std::basic_ostream`'s constructor is protected.  Your class (or a parent thereof) has a `std::basic_ostream` (or maybe `std::ostream`) member, which cannot be default-constructed.  You must construct it with an argument.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3at5becw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) shows that it must be cosntructed from a `basic_streambuf<Elem, Tr>*`.

Now I'm going to extrapolate: You probably don't actually want a `std::ostream` member in your class, you probably want a specific-derived type, or you want a reference, or (most likely) a an unknown or changable derived type.  But since the nieve way to address the first two cases makes your class non-copiable, the final solution is virtually always the same: Use a `std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>` instead if your class owns the stream, or a `std::ostream*` if someone else owns it.

Finally: The full text for errors is in the "output" window of Visual Studio, not in the "Error" Window, which just shows summaries.  The full text of that error would have many more details about the error, including (most likely) the name and line number of your class' default constructor.